# Sql condition with two foriegn key columns

Tags: sql-server

```
    I'm new to sql and
    have a table dbo.Student




**column**                             **datatype**
     Student Id Primary Key            int not null
    ClassId Foriegn Key                int not null
    BaseId        Foriegn Key          int not null
```

ClassId can have multiple base Id but not duplicates
    I'm looking to write a condition If any ClassId have duplicate rows with same BaseId's

```
    Example for good data
    a b  c
    1 2  1
    2 2  2
    Example for bad data
    a b  c
    1 2  1
    2 2  1


    Thanks
```

Comment: There are "unique" constraints in SQL server.  You can add one to that column and it will prevent the entry of a row in which that column value is not unique.  Unique constraints are allowed on columns that are not keys.  This SO answer has both the gui solution and script solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181877/how-can-i-create-a-unique-constraint-on-my-column-sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "unique" constraints in SQL server. You can add one to that column and it will prevent the entry of a row in which that column value is not unique. Unique constraints are allowed on columns that are not keys.

This SO answer has both the gui solution and script solution:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/5181877/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181877/)

Gist of linked answer:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName UNIQUE(ColumnName1, ColumnName2)
```

This will put a unique constraint on the combination of Column1 and Column2.

In SSMS object Explorer if you expand the table and look under "Keys" to see your constraint.

GUI steps:

```
Open SQL Server Management Studio.
Expand the Tables folder of the database where you want to create the 
constraint.
Right-click the table where you want to add the constraint and click Design.
In the Table Designer menu, click Indexes/Keys.
In the Indexes/Keys dialog box, click Add.
Choose Unique Key in the Type drop-down list.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to check if you have any duplicate rows in the table

```
select ClassId,baseid, COUNT(*) NumberOfDuplicate
from student
group by ClassId,baseid
having count(*) >1
```