# How can use alter table column and add constraint in single query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In MySQL I use:

```
alter table (table name)
    modify column name varchar(255) not null unique
```

How to use same query in SQL Server?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean add const*rai*nt?

Comment: SQL Server Version?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes add constraint - UNIQUE

Comment: Hi @VivekMahajan if the below answer (or a future answer) has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested this. For SQL Server 2008 and above:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ALTER COLUMN column_name varchar(255) not null;
```

Apparently, the [unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181877/how-can-i-create-a-unique-constraint-on-my-column-sql-server-2008-r2) cannot be on the same command, so.. no, you can't put that in a single query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE(column_name);
```

Change the `table_name`, `column_name` and `constraint_name` accordingly.

Reference: [learn.microsoft.com - Alter Table (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#alter_column)