# SQL Server Management Studio Null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ssms

I try to understand what null value is in SQL. See the following screenshot.

My question is: if I allow null, does it mean that it is null or not? I mean if I fill in the box (see the picture) does it mean it is null?

[image: Click to see the screenshot]

Comment: Just as a side note: `NULL` is really not a value - it's the **absence** of a value, really. So if a column is `NULL`, it means that there is no value defined for this column yet ....

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I fill the box under "Allow Nulls", does it become Null? Hope you understand what I mean...

Comment: If you check the "Allow Nulls" - then you **allow** the column to be null / undefined. If you haven't checked this box, then you **require** the column to always have a non-NULL value

Comment: Ahh I get it now!! You helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Setting `null` or `not null` does not change the values of anything in the data.

It simply specifies whether you can `insert` or `update` values to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer, but if I fill the box under "Allow Nulls", does it become Null? Hope you understand what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a value for the column that allows null value, then it becomes null after insert or update. You can also specify the default value for the column, look at my screenshot.[image]

Comment: I see, I need help with another thing. I want to prevent duplicate inserts into database, do you know an easey way?

Comment: Add a primary key or unique index on the column you don't want any duplicates of.

Comment: But the primary key in this case is the Id, my table contains only ID and CategoryName, I dont want any dublicates of CategoryName. And since the id is the primary key I connot set the other one to primary key can I ?

Comment: Add a unique index to this field. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181877/how-can-i-create-a-unique-constraint-on-my-column-sql-server-2008-r2